# Vue Select Component w/computed model doesn't show correct value under specific conditions

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I've run into a computed property issue that I'm unsure how it should work.  Here's the Issue Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ibigpapa/6zgno1eu/4/

The problem is when the currently selected value is the Default value and I select the `--reset--` option, I would expect the computed property to correctly reset the value to Default.  Instead on the select box visually it stays on `--reset--`.

Now if you select another option so it's no longer the Default value.  Then select the `--reset--` option it will change the value and the select box visually back to Default.

How should you set this value in this instance?

I worked around the issue by hiding the option when the current value is the Default value.  I still like to figure out if there is a way to do it fully inside the computed value.

Workaround Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ibigpapa/ou865d4x/12/

Comment: How to use a different 'model'. Keep that in mind.https://jsfiddle.net/kdydesign30/56xtuoz7/1/

Comment: I cannot replicate this. It goes back to `--Filter Values--` for me.

Answer (score 0):

The computer property valueComp is based on value of data,the value is null in default,when you selected the --reset--,you reset the value to null again, the set of computer property valueComp will not work if the value have not changed,so the dom will not rerender,so you must find a way to change the value,here is the instance.

```js
set: function (value) {
        console.log(value)
       if (value === '--reset--') {
         this.value = '';
        } else if (value === '') {
          this.value = null;
        } else {
         this.value = value;
        }
      }
```